# Number of solutions of parametric linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have some problems trying to find the number of solutions for this linear system (with $\lambda \in \Bbb R$):

$$
\begin{cases}
x+y+2z+3t=\lambda \\
y+z+\lambda t = -1 \\
x+2y+3z+4t=0
\end{cases}
$$

or:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & \lambda & \lambda \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and:
$$
b=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda \\
-1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

At a first glance I noticed that $rank(A)$ should be at least 2 $\forall \lambda \in \Bbb R$ since:

$$
M_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, det(M_2)\neq0
$$

and also that if $\lambda = 1$:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
, 
b=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then:
$$r_3 = r_1+r_2$$
and then:
$$rank(A) = rank(Ab) = 2$$
For Rouche-Capelli theorem the system should have $\infty^2$ solutions:
$$
y=t+x-3, z=2-2t-x
$$

then if $\lambda = 0:$

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
, 
b=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

we have:
$$
M_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}, det(M_3) \neq0
$$

$$
rank(A)=rank(Ab)=3
$$
For Rouche-Capelli theorem the system should have $\infty$ solutions:
$$
x=-t-1, y=-1,  z=1-t
$$

but now I have no more ideas .. and I'm long from having completed my task.
Any hints?

Comment: In the first set of equations you have "$x+2x+3z+4t=0$" Is this a typo? Also, Matrix A does not correspond to the system in the 1st equation.

Comment: You have 3 equations and 4 variables (5 if you count lambda).  This system has a non trivial kernel and thus has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Why do you think that there’s anything left to do?

Comment: @NoChance yes it is a typo. I'm going to fix it.

Comment: @amd because I forgot to mention that I have to find out how many solutions the system will have per $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. Now I added this to the question text.

Comment: @DougM yes the system will probably have $\infty^n$ solutions we have to find $n$ (in function on $\lambda$ values).

Comment: You’ve done that. Why do you think that there are any other possibilities beyond the one’s that you’ve found?

Comment: @amd maybe I understimate my genius but I think NoChance answer is more complete and formal than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a typo (as in the comment above) your system becomes:

$$
\begin{cases}
x+y+2z+3t=\lambda \\
y+z+\lambda t = -1 \\
x+2y+3z+4t=0
\end{cases}
$$

I am assuming that $\lambda$ is a constant.

Write the last equation as:

$$x+y+2z+3t+y+z+t=0$$

From equation (1) this is $=\lambda$, so it becomes

$$(x+y+2z+3t)+y+z+t=0$$

Which is:

$$y+z+t=-\lambda$$

Use this value in equation (1) to get:

$$x+z+2t-\lambda=\lambda$$

So the system becomes:

$$
\begin{cases}
x+z+2t=2\lambda \\
y+z+\lambda t = -1 \\
y+z+t=-\lambda
\end{cases}
$$

Manipulating equations (2) and (3) in the above system results (assuming $\lambda$ is not equal 1):
$t=1$

When you plug this value in you get the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+z=2\lambda-2 \\
y+z=-\lambda -1 \\
y+z=-\lambda -1
\end{cases}
$$

The last equation is redundant. So we have 2 equations and 3 variables. You may choose to use $x=ky$ where $k$ is a nonzero constant. to get a system of $2$ equations and $2$ variables. This will lead to a infinite number of solutions since k can assume any non-zero value.

Comment: Uhm nice idea but it seems that you have some sign error in $x+z+2t−\lambda=−\lambda$ it should be $x+z+2t−\lambda=\lambda$.

Comment: The final system complete and incomplete matrixes share the same $rank()$ and this's equal to 2 so the number of solutions with $\lambda \neq 1$ is $\infty^1$. Thnx.

Comment: @weirdgyn, thank you kindly. You are very polite. I will correct.